# strip newlines and paragraph breaks from srt file

Tags: scripting, awk

I use this script to remove timestamps from subtitles.

```
awk '/-->/{for(i=1;i<d;i++){print a[i]};delete a;d=0;next}{a[++d]=$0}
    END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' xxxxx.srt > xxx.txt
```

I then paste the result into a web page that removes line breaks and paragraph breaks. To have just one paragraph and it its a space instead of the break. Been going there:
https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php

I have been looking for a solution to do all of this into one command but I can't find how to.
I know there are other options than awk, anything that accomplishes this task easily from the mac terminal works for me!

Please help?

Here is an example subtitle I want to format and it doesn't work. I see that some are working ... this is weird.

[subtitle file](https://ufile.io/yun57xua)

expected output:

```
Welcome to our program! This month’s theme is “Are You Paying Attention?” Strained relationships, illnesses, careers, entertainment —we’ll learn how to stay focused on Jehovah despite these potential distractions. We’ll see how our ministry is more effective when we focus on reaching the hearts of people. And our new song was written especially for you young adults to help you keep your eyes on the prize of life.
```

But this is what I get with your script:

```
    Welcome to our program!
 
 2
 00:00:06,089 --> 00:00:08,624
 This month’s theme is
 
 3
 00:00:08,625 --> 00:00:11,126
 “Are You Paying Attention?”
 
 4
 00:00:11,127 --> 00:00:13,595
 Strained relationships,
 
 5
 00:00:13,596 --> 00:00:16,131
 illnesses,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` in "paragraph mode":

```
awk -v RS= '{
    for (i=5;i<=NF;i++){
      printf "%s%s", (sep ? " " : ""), $i
      sep=1
    }
  }
  END{ print "" }
' file.srt > file.txt
```

This sets the record separator to a null string and records are separated by empty lines.
The first four fields per record are skipped (field 1 is the line number, fields 2-4 the display time) and the other fields are printed with a prefixed space character
except for the very first field.

At the end, print a single newline.

Input file:

```
1
00:00:06,453 --> 00:00:10,579
When one chooses to walk
the Way of the Mandalore,

2
00:00:10,581 --> 00:00:14,095
you are both hunter and prey.

3
00:00:17,935 --> 00:00:20,076
There is one job.

4
00:00:20,078 --> 00:00:21,945
Underworld?

5
00:00:21,947 --> 00:00:26,118
How uncharacteristic of
one of your reputation.
```

Output:

```
When one chooses to walk the Way of the Mandalore, you are both hunter and prey. There is one job. Underworld? How uncharacteristic of one of your reputation.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Weird because any other subtitle I try it prints the 1rst line ok but then the other lines have a space added.

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/617375/edit) your question and provide a) sample input or a link to a subtitle that doesn't work and add b) the expected output.

Comment: I entered the correct info with the bug.

Comment: The given file is UTF-8 with Byte Order Mark (BOM) and Windows-style CR/LF line terminators (check with `file jwb_E_202011_01_r240P.srt`).
You can convert it with `dos2unix jwb_E_202011_01_r240P.srt` before running the script.

Comment: Wow that worked! I am using ccextractor which says they do not use bom on non-windows machines, tried adding the -nobom and it didn't change anything. It says UTF-8 is now the default, I don't get why it's creating this format then.